# ExtJS 6 configure Ext.ux

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I'm trying to use the color picker under ext/packages/ux/classic/src/colorpicker
So I set my requires :

```
requires: [
        'Ext.plugin.Viewport',
        'Ext.window.MessageBox',


        'ThemeDemoApp.view.main.MainController',
        'ThemeDemoApp.view.main.MainModel',
        'ThemeDemoApp.view.main.List',
        'Ext.slider.Single',
        'Ext.ux.colorpick.Button'
    ]
```

And at the top of app.js, I set this :

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({                enabled : true,
                paths   : {
                        'Ext.ux' : 'ext/packages/ux/classic/src'
                } 
        });
```

But it's not working I have : 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:1841/ext/classic/cl...=1437726506841

It doesn't take my loader configuration. How can I configure Ext.ux correctly ?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you are using Sencha CMD (because of localhost:1841), in which case there is no need to configure `Ext.Loader`. Merely specifying `Ext.ux.colorpick.Button` in the `requires` declaration should work.

Comment: Yes I use sencha CMD 6 but same error if I don't specify loader config. That why I try to configure it :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure that your `app.json` requires `ux`:

```
"requires": [
    // ...
    "ux"
]
```

Also, as you are using Sencha CMD there is no need to worry about `Ext.Loader`.

Comment: how to include it in extjs422 ?

Comment: @Sparrow sorry dude I haven't used ExtJS for years, can't remember. But I would go check the examples.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i configured my web application that uses Ext.ux. Take a look:
[image]

As you can see i added ext-ux folder with ***all interested for me*** sources inside webapp.
In `app.js` i added:

`Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', 'extjs/ext-ux/src/ux');`

In `index.jsp` i added:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-ux/ext-ux-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
```

Of course paths will change depends on your configuration.

And example to show how to use it:

```
Ext.define('ScuWeb.ScuWebApp', {
    extend: 'Ext.ux.desktop.App',

    requires: [
        'Ext.window.MessageBox',
        'Ext.ux.desktop.ShortcutModel'
    ],
```

Comment: how did u get ext-ux-debug file?

Answer (score 0):

With EXT Js, using Sencha CMD, adding requires [...,"ux"] is sufficient.